# wordpress blog excerpt prestation

Tags: performance, wordpress, time, blogs

I don't know how this page of my web site, takes much time to load:
michelepierri.it/blog 
In this page there are post excerpts of blog.

Instead other pages like home page, take less time to load.

What can be causing this?
Thanks a lot.

Plugins I use:

```
Advanced Code Editor
All in One SEO Pack
Better Related Content
cbnet Twitter Widget
CloudFlare
Contact Form 7
Default Thumbnail Plus
Developer Formatter
Disqus Comment System
Fancybox
Fast Secure Contact Form
FeedBurner FeedSmith Extend
Google Analytics
Google XML Sitemaps
lorem shortcode
NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster
Official StatCounter Plugin
Pingler
Really Simple CAPTCHA
Shareaholic | email, bookmark, share buttons
Simple Skype Status
Single Category Permalink
Skype Online Status
Social Metrics
SyntaxHighlighter Plus
Transposh Filtro per Traduzioni
Trash Manager
W3 Total Cache
WP-Cumulus
WP-o-Matic
WP Facebook Open Graph protocol
WP Minify
WP to Twitter
Youtube shortcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so many plugins? That can actually impact your performance a fair amount. The first request to your site is taking a long time, which actually suggests a server issue (more likely to be an issue if you're on shared hosting with the number of plugins active).